# How to make openBLAS work with openMP?

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp, openblas

I got tons of warning from openBLAS like

`OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.`

Here is what my src/Makevars file looks like

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

And here is my header file:

```
#define ARMA_NO_DEBUG

#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif

//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppProgress)]]
#include <progress.hpp>

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <R.h>
```

openMP is used in my code like this

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(n_threads) schedule(dynamic) private(W, mu)
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < m; j++)
```

where `n_threads` is passed via function argument. Everything is fine when `n_threads = 1` but got the above warnings when `n_threads = 2`.
A complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/linxihui/NNLM/blob/master/src/update_with_missing.cpp), which depends on other files as well (sorry I cannot paste here as it is a bit long).

I tried adding `USE_OPENMP=1` to src/Makevars, but it does not work. Any body has a solution? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post a _complete and reproducible example_ rather than mere snippets?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for quick reply. The code is big long and depends on others, but you can see it on my github [here](https://github.com/linxihui/NNLM/blob/master/src/update_with_missing.cpp).  Does it sound OK, or too much that I should probably create a standalone similar but smaller example?

Comment: It's easy: If you want help, _make it easy for us to help you_.  I am sorry but I don't have time to chase yet another random GH repo.  And for starters: consider 1) Remove RcppProgress and 2) Check the Rcpp Gallery examples for OpenMP.  This stuff generally works.  OpenMP is even used inside R.  But without a reproducible example ...

Answer (score 3):

I got the same warnings while running Torch on CPU mode. Rebuilding OpenBLAS with OPEN_MP 1 fixed it for me.

If you want to rebuild OpenBLAS with OPEN_MP 1, then:

Go to the folder where you cloned OpenBLAS repository (for me it is /home/brt/code/OpenBLAS)

```
cd /home/brt/code/OpenBLAS/
make clean
make USE_OPENMP=1
sudo make install
```

if you have not already done so,

```
sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openblas.conf
```

add the line:  /opt/OpenBLAS/lib

save and close

```
sudo ldconfig
```

This should rebuild OpenBLAS with OPEN_MP as 1

Comment: Is there a conda install that takes care of this?