# OpenMP threaded C program stalls when calling python script (using matplotlib) in parallel region

Tags: python, c, matplotlib, openmp, openblas

I have a C program that is multithreaded using OpenMP. Within the parallel for section of the code, a system call is made to a python script that plots the data generated in that particular iteration of the loop. I have an issue where the program suddenly stalls out at the same point after thousands of iterations and hours of running. After running `ps -A` to see what processes were running at the stall, I noticed n-many instances of python (where n = number of threads), which led to me believe something was happening with the python script. I switched from a system call to the python script to embedded python, hoping that might solve the issue. What I am seeing now is that running the python script produces the warning:

```
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
```

I am not using anything BLAS related in my code, but after trial and error I found that this is being produced by matplotlib, which is dependent on numpy which in turn, I gather, uses OpenBLAS. I suspect that this may be the culprit behind the eventual stall, but I am not sure how to fix it. I tried to install OpenBLAS from the GitHub page and make it with the `USE_OPENMP=1` flag as outlined here:

[How to make openBLAS work with openMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578526/how-to-make-openblas-work-with-openmp)

This, I suppose unsurprisingly, did not resolve the issue. I suspect I would have to remake whatever source of BLAS that matplotlib is using? In any case, I have supplied a minimal example that reproduces the undesirable behavior. The OpenMP C code is here:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
#include "omp.h"

int NUM_THREADS = 8;        // Default number of threads for OpenMP

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   # ifdef _OPENMP
   printf("Compiled by an OpenMP-compliant implementation.\n");
   # endif

   omp_set_dynamic(0);
   omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

   int nThreads = 0;

   #pragma omp parallel
   {

   #pragma omp master
   nThreads = omp_get_num_threads();

   #pragma omp for
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)  // Loop through number of samples
   {
     // Create directories to store and run the python script
     char system_buffer[300] = "\0";
     snprintf(system_buffer, sizeof(system_buffer), "mkdir -p %d", i+1);
     int systemRet = system(system_buffer);
     if(systemRet == -1)
     {
       // The system method failed
     }

     // Copy the Python Script to the working directory
     char system_buffer_py[300] = "\0";
     snprintf(system_buffer_py, sizeof(system_buffer_py), "cp test.py %d", i+1);
     int systemRet_py = system(system_buffer_py);
     if(systemRet_py == -1)
     {
       // The system method failed
     }

     int pid;

     // Child
     if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
     {
       int argc = 0;
       char* argv[1];
       argv[0] = NULL;

       char python_script[300] = "\0";
       snprintf(python_script, sizeof(python_script), "%d/test.py", i+1);

       FILE *stream = fopen(python_script, "r");

       Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
       Py_Initialize();
       PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
       PyRun_AnyFile(stream, python_script);
       Py_Finalize();

       fclose(stream);

       exit(0);
     } 
     // Parent
     else
     {
       int status;
       waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
     }
   }

   }//end of: pragma omp parallel

   if  (nThreads == NUM_THREADS) 
   {
     printf("The expected number of threads, %d, were used.\n", NUM_THREADS);
   }
   else 
   {
     printf("Expected %d OpenMP threads, but %d were used.\n", NUM_THREADS, nThreads);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

This can be compiled using:

```
gcc -Wall -O3 -fopenmp test.c -o test -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython2.7 -ldl -export-dynamic -lm
```

The python script is here and should be in the same directory as the C code:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plot_name = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/test.png'

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.savefig(plot_name)
```

The output from running the C Code is:

```
Compiled by an OpenMP-compliant implementation.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
The expected number of threads, 8, were used.
```

So it appears this warning is being thrown 3 times for each thread (using 8 threads). Any input on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mixing threads and `fork()` is possible, but *extremely* involved. In essence, after you have multiple threads running, you *cannot* use any async-unsafe function after you `fork()`, until you `exec()`. You certainly *cannot* run a Python interpreter in the un-`exec()`ed child process.

Comment: Fair enough point. I was originally just using system(), which is basically fork() and exec() with the overhead of the shell. The consensus I am reading is that a fork() followed by an immediate exec() is essentially threadsafe, which I can do with the python script calling matplotlib. I suspect the OpenBLAS issue will remain...

Comment: Also, another thing worth noting is that I also parallelized this program using MPI rather than OpenMP, which obviously doesn’t use threads at all, just multiple instances of the program. The same stall occurred at the same spot. I’ll try the embedded python approach with that version to see if a similar type of warning appears from the python script.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that a link could not be an answer, but since I never tried to mix threads and fork().  [This article](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them) could help.