# Identifying source of and understanding OpenBLAS and OpenMP warnings

Tags: python, openmp, warnings, pytorch-lightning, openblas

I am developing a deep learning model using `pytorch`, `pytorch-lightning`, and `segmentation-models-pytorch`. When I run `pytorch_lightning.Trainer.fit()`, I get hundreds of the following warning:

```
OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option.
```

I have the following questions:

1. How can I identify what part of my code or the source code is raising this warning?
2. How can I assess whether this warning is relevant or can be ignored?
3. If I decide I can ignore the warning, how can I suppress the warning?

I am familiar with handling warnings through python's `warnings` module. However, this doesn't help here because the warning is coming from `OpenBLAS`, which is not a python library.

There are several other questions about how to fix the problem that causes this warning, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578526/how-to-make-openblas-work-with-openmp) and [here](https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/issues/2197). My question is about understanding the source of the warning, deciding whether I care about it, and suppressing it if I don't care.

Thanks in advance for any tips or answers to the above questions. Apologies if these are silly or poorly formulated questions, as I am completely unfamiliar with `OpenBLAS` and `OpenMP`.

Answer (score 1):

OpenBLAS is a low-level library providing fast implementation of (most if not all) linear algebra operations, and OpenMP provides primitives for parallel computing on shared memory machines.

Pytorch, as well as other ML/sci-computing libraries, uses one or both libraries. For instance, Numpy is based on openBLAS which guarantees very fast matrix operations, scikit-learn uses OpenMP for executing parallel jobs.

One problem is that OpenBLAS is built using OpenMP. Numerical computing libraries require for building specific versions of OpenBLAS (some specific build configuration for OpenMP) which can conflicts with other libraries that may depend also on OpenMP for their build.

Here is more information about how these dependencies are managed across different package distros: https://pypackaging-native.github.io/key-issues/native-dependencies/blas_openmp/

According to the same source, PyTorch makes use of OpenMP and do not specify explicitly which openMP instance to use or how to use it. This conflicts with other multi-threading libraries and can cause building issues.

The warning raised by OpenBLAS in your case means the openBLAS detects multiple OpenMP threads which is unexpected (see https://github.com/open-ce/pytorch-feedstock/issues/34 and https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/52047,https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/issues/2197).

A solution which is proposed to solve this problem from PyTorch side (since it is the root cause in our case) is to tell PyTorch to use another available parallel computing dependency called TBB (see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cpu_threading_torchscript_inference.html). It goes by setting USE_TBB=1 when building Torch.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful information. However, it doesn't really answer my core questions about (1) identifying the specific line(s) of code that are raising the warning, (2) assessing whether I care about the warning (for example, if the threat is that the app may hang, but it doesn't, I think I can ignore the warning), and (3) suppressing the warning. I will try re-building pytorch with TBB, but it would be nice to know if there is a simpler solution to the problem, in particular one that allows me not to re-build pytorch from source and instead use the default version on `conda-forge`.

Comment: I am sorry  I didnt answer your specific questions explicitly, but in my opinion, I think there is not a simple answes to them.
(1.) 
Its pytorch library, inside `.fit()` method, that is calling openBLAS which then raises this warning since pytorch uses also the same dependency directly and implicitly..

(2.)  This warning indicates a potential issue with the configuration of OpenBLAS that could lead to hangs or performance problems. Ignoring it might result in unpredictable behavior or suboptimal performance.
(3.) Maybe you should rebuild OpenBLAS so that it won't raises warnings :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due a [conflict](https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/blob/develop/USAGE.md#how-can-i-use-openblas-in-multi-threaded-applications) between `pytorch_lightning` inner calls to OpenMP and underlying `openBLAS`. To mitigate the problem, try to follow the recommendation and

```
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1
```

before running Python. (In case you are on Windows set this as environmental variable).

This message means that some pieces of the code call the same function over and over again, without waiting for the previous call to finish. The consequence of this issue is that sometimes you might get different results for the same batch of data during the training phase, depending on the CPU load.

As this does not happen directly in your code, but in the compiled library there is no way to catch it or suppress the warning from the Python code.

See also this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104472/why-would-setting-export-openblas-num-threads-1-impair-the-performance).